# Mysql comma count from field value

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

I want to count string separators from a MySQL query, mean if the field value is 
like :-

```
 1,2,3,4,5
```

as the string is comma separated so the separator count will be 4.

any idea then please share

THANKS,

Comment: Seems like you need to check if there is a string manipulation function that will split a string by a separator, and then count the number of parts that result. You should get n+1 parts for n commas.

Comment: why do you store seperated strings as values ? this only complicates and reduces database performance. What are you trying to do exactly ?

Comment: giorashc - we don't always get to choose the data we have to work with. Why not ask him something that might help you answer his question?

Comment: @giorashc i'm trying to store users hobbies separated by comma. if you have alternate solution then please give

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to count the length of string and minus the length of string without commas as follows:

```
LENGTH('1,2,3,4,5') - LENGTH(REPLACE('1,2,3,4,5', ',', ''))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select length('1,2,3,4,5') - length(replace('1,2,3,4,5', ',', ''))
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following design :

```
Table name : USER_HOBBIES

| USER_ID | HOBBY_ID |
     1         1
     1         2
     1         3
     2         2
     2         4
     2         5
```

And now you can easily count user hobbies for a given user :

```
SELECT count(*) FROM USER_HOBBIES WHERE USER_ID = <user-id>
```

although it requires another table it is much clearer and on a long list of hobbies this will be much faster than using a function for manipulating strings.